# Как правильно задавать вопрос на SO (юмор)

Tags: обсуждение

Попытался восстановить этот алгоритм в соответствии с наблюдаемыми фактами.

1. Открываем браузер
2. Пишем: "яндекс", переходим на Яндекс
3. Пишем: "гугл", переходим в гугл
4. Пишем: "stackoverflow", переходим на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
5. Задаем вопрос на английском языке от анонимного пользователя
6. Ждем ответа
7. Замечаем, что кто-то перевел вопрос на русский

---

8. Открываем новую вкладку браузера
9. Пишем: "яндекс", переходим на Яндекс
10. Пишем: "гугл", переходим в гугл
11. Пишем: "stackoverflow support", переходим на https://stackoverflow.com/contact
12. Пишем возмущенное письмо, что кто-то перевел вопрос на русский, хотя он задавался в англоязычное сообщество

*Что происходит дальше, прошу дописать того кто знает*

Comment: дальше надо идти в прокуратору, и писать письмо президенту!

Comment: мне кажется слово юмор нужно ещё раз 5 написать... Теги всё равно никто не читает)

Comment: остается непонятным почему человек который способен задать вопрос на английском пишет "яндекс"

Comment: @pavel, наоборот - меткам не место в заголовке:)

Comment: @Утка, потому что раскладка на русском :)

Comment: @Утка потому что мне всегда было смешно от использования поисковиков вместо строки адреса, вот и приплел сюда мамин способ попасть на гугл.

Comment: @Grundy нынче модно писать в Спортлото.

Comment: @PavelMayorov видели историю с группой Яндекса в одноклассниках, на стену которой люди постили собственные запросы?